# t-sql complex query to get only maximum status with 'R'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to get the maximum claim status version with status type only with 'R' and if there other status with the same claim id I want to filter those.

Below query doesn't give me the required results.

```
select p.prov_clm_id,p.prov_clm_stat_type,max(p.clm_stat_version)
from provider_clm_stat p 
WHERE p.provider_clm_stat_type='R' 
GROUP BY p.prov_clm_id,p.provider_claim_status_type


194 R   1
231 R   1
469 R   1
649 R   1
```

If there are other claim status I don't want to show it in my results.

```
select * from provider_clm_stat where prov_clm_id=194


194 5   B
194 2   K
194 3   G
194 4   Q
194 7   H
194 8   P
194 1   R
194 6   X


Required results:

740 R   1
```

Comment: Where does the `740` come from in the required results?

Comment: 740 is the claim id which only has status type 'R'

Comment: You want the claim ids that *only* have status `'R'` and no other statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the claim status that only have `'R'` and no other statuses:

```
select p.prov_clm_id, p.prov_clm_stat_type, max(p.clm_stat_version)
from provider_clm_stat p 
GROUP BY p.prov_clm_id, p.provider_claim_status_type
having max(p.provider_clm_stat_type) = 'R' and
       min(p.provider_clm_stat_type) = 'R';
```

The filtering here is in the `having` clause *after* the aggregation.  If the `min()` and `max()` values are both `'R'`, then all values are `'R'` or `NULL`.  If `NULL` is a possibility and you want to filter it out, use this clause:

```
having max(p.provider_clm_stat_type) = 'R' and
       min(p.provider_clm_stat_type) = 'R' and
       count(*) = count(p.provider_clm_stat_type)
```

Comment: Still not getting the required results. I am not able to filter the claims which are received alone. there are other status types for the same claim IDs.

Comment: @user3120927 . . . If you are using these queries -- *without the `where` clause* -- then all the status types are the same and are `'R'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by what data you are looking for, but perhaps something like this:

```
select TOP 1 p.prov_clm_id,p.prov_clm_stat_type, p.clm_stat_version
from provider_clm_stat p 
WHERE p.provider_clm_stat_type='R' 
ORDER BY p.clm_stat_version desc
```

From what I can tell, the group by does nothing for you, since you have the Id in the grouping.

Edited: changed the order by field and removed the max.

Comment: I suspect the app wants more than just one row, though; e.g. all of the IDs that only have status = R.

Comment: "I want to get the maximum claim status version with status type only with 'R' and if there other status with the same claim id I want to filter those."  Kind of hard to decipher, but he did use a singular "claim status version", and in his example, he listed a single row as the desired result.  But, I reserve the right to be completely wrong!  :)